# Right outer JOIN in SQL

Tags: sql

I have to list all departments, which do not have any employees assigned to but I don't know how to solve this with a outer-join. The scheme of the database is:

[image: database scheme]

My current statement is

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.department_name 
FROM departments d 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN employees e ON NOT e.department_id IS NULL;
```

but it doesn't work as it should.

My result is this:

[image: my result]

It should look like this:

[image: expected result]

Does anybody know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right this as an `outer left join` like so, correlating on the `department_id`

```
SELECT d.department_name 
FROM departments d 
LEFT JOIN employees e ON e.department_id=d.department_Id
WHERE e.employee_id is null
```

Or a more intuitive version would be where there *does not exist* any employees for a department_id

```
SELECT d.department_name
FROM departments d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM employees e WHERE e.department_id=d.department_Id )
```